# How to count overlap rows in multiple dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas

I have multiple dataframes like below.

[image]

The dataframe has 3 columns and sometimes their rows overlap among the dataframes.
(e.g. df1 and df2 has an identical row as "aaa, bbb, ccc").

I want to know how the rows overlap among dataframes and want to make an output like below.

[image]

In this output, if an identical row is detected in the dataframe, the output will be 1, otherwise 0.
Does anyone know how to make this output?

In the actual data, I have ~100 dataframes.
I first tried to use pd.merge but could not apply this to 100 dataframes...

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: If you can put your data as text instead of pictures, you would get faster response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    [["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"], ["ddd", "eee", "fff"], ["ggg", "hhh", "iii"]],
    columns=["Col1", "Col2", "Col3"],
)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    [["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"], ["zzz", "xxx", "yyy"], ["qqq", "eee", "www"]],
    columns=["Col1", "Col2", "Col3"],
)

df3 = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        ["rrr", "ttt", "yyy"],
        ["zzz", "xxx", "yyy"],
        ["qqq", "eee", "www"],
        ["ppp", "ttt", "qqq"],
    ],
    columns=["Col1", "Col2", "Col3"],
)

df_x = (
    pd.get_dummies(
        pd.concat({"df1": df1, "df2": df2, "df3": df3}).reset_index(),
        columns=["level_0"],
        prefix="",
        prefix_sep="",
    )
    .drop("level_1", axis=1)
    .groupby(by=["Col1", "Col2", "Col3"])
    .sum()
)

print(df_x)
```

Yields:

```
                df1  df2  df3
Col1 Col2 Col3               
aaa  bbb  ccc     1    1    0
ddd  eee  fff     1    0    0
ggg  hhh  iii     1    0    0
ppp  ttt  qqq     0    0    1
qqq  eee  www     0    1    1
rrr  ttt  yyy     0    0    1
zzz  xxx  yyy     0    1    1
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted! Thank you very much!!